# Angular variable values vanish after reloading

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm building a ring of fire-clone in angular with firebase as a backend. Everything worked fine until now. I wanted to add some functionality which shows a name and some avatar picture to it. This works, too, but when I reload the page and add some new player, the old ones disappear.
I'm pretty sure it has sth. to do with the initial loading of the game data, but I'm relatively new to angular and I'm not able to fix it after ...hours ;)

Dialog-component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { GameComponent } from '../game/game.component';
import { AddService } from '../add-service/add.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

interface Avatar {
  value: number;
  viewValue: any;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-add-player',
  templateUrl: './dialog-add-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-add-player.component.scss'],
})
export class DialogAddPlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string = '';
  avatars: Avatar[] = [];
  selectedAvatar: any;
  currentId!: any;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAddPlayerComponent>,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public gameComponent: GameComponent
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.getCurrentId();
    this.getAvatarImages();
  }

  onNoClick() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  async sendPlayerData() {
    let newPlayer = { name: this.name, avatars: this.selectedAvatar };
    let stringData = JSON.stringify(newPlayer);
    await this.gameComponent.addPlayer(stringData, this.currentId);
  }

  async getCurrentId() {
    this.currentId = localStorage.getItem('id');
  }

  getAvatarImages() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
      this.avatars.push({
        value: i,
        viewValue: '/assets/img/avatars_withbg/' + i + '.png',
        name: this.names[i - 1],
      });
    }
  }

  names = [
    'Elowen',
    'Aldric',
    'Thorn',
    'Maelis',
    'Caelan',
    'Brynn',
    'Eowyn',
    'Lysander',
    'Rowena',
    'Crispin',
    'Seraphina',
    'Oswin',
    'Lorelei',
    'Cassian',
    'Elysia',
    'Aurelius',
    'Ilythia',
    'Orin',
    'Morgana',
    'Finnian',
    'Genevieve',
    'Peregrine',
    'Elara',
    'Quinlan',
    'Seraphim',
    'Rhiannon',
    'Cedric',
    'Ondine',
    'Eadric',
    'Isolde',
    'Thaddeus',
    'Aurora',
    'Gawain',
    'Artemis',
    'Calista',
    'Gareth',
    'Thalassa',
    'Cyprian',
    'Eulalia',
    'Drystan',
    'Morgause',
    'Ezrael',
    'Eirian',
    'Faelan',
    'Sylvaine',
    'Lorcan',
    'Morrigan',
    'Fiora',
    'Finlo',
    'Danilo',
  ];
}
```

Game-component:

```
    import { Component, Injectable, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Firestore,
  collectionData,
  collection,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Game } from 'src/models/game';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
  MatDialogRef,
  MatDialogModule,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { DialogAddPlayerComponent } from '../dialog-add-player/dialog-add-player.component';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { onSnapshot } from '@firebase/firestore';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.scss'],
})
@Injectable()
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {
  game: Game = new Game();

  unsubGamesList;
  unsubSingleDoc;
  currentId: string = '';
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.unsubGamesList = onSnapshot(this.getGamesRef(), (list: any) => {
      list.forEach((element: any) => {
        //console.log(element.data());
      });
    });

    this.unsubSingleDoc = onSnapshot(
      this.getSingleDocRef('games', '1234'),
      (doc) => {}
    );
  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    //route gibt url-rest zurück --> dieser ist gleichzeitig die firebase-id und kann
    // so über einen snapshot-listener das zugehörige spiel anzeigen und updaten
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.unsubSingleDoc = onSnapshot(
        this.getSingleDocRef('games', params['id']),
        (gameDoc) => {
          const gameData = gameDoc.data();
          this.currentId = params['id'];
          localStorage.setItem('id', this.currentId);
          if (gameData) {
            this.game.currentPlayer = gameData['currentPlayer'];
            this.game.playedCards = gameData['playedCards'];
            this.game.players = this.getNames(gameData['players']);
            this.game.stack = gameData['stack'];
            this.game.pickCardAnimation = gameData['pickCardAnimation'];
            this.game.currentCard = gameData['currentCard'];
            this.game.avatarId = this.getAvatars(gameData['players']);;
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }

  getNames(playersList: any) {
    const namesArray = playersList.map((jsonString: string) => {
      const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      return jsonObject.name;
    });
    return namesArray;
  }

  getAvatars(playersList: any){
    const avatarArray = playersList.map((jsonString: string) => {
      const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      return jsonObject.avatars;
    });
    return avatarArray;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubGamesList();
    this.unsubSingleDoc();
  }

  getGamesRef() {
    return collection(this.firestore, 'games');
  }

  getSingleDocRef(colId: string, docId: string) {
    return doc(collection(this.firestore, colId), docId);
  }

  async addGame(item: {}) {
    await addDoc(this.getGamesRef(), item)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Adding document failed: ' + err);
      })
      .then((docRef: any) => {
        this.currentId = docRef.id;
        console.log('Document written with id: ' + docRef.id);
      });
  }

  async updateGame() {
    if (this.currentId) {
      try {
        let gameDocRef = this.getSingleDocRef('games', this.currentId);
        await updateDoc(gameDocRef, this.game.toJson());
        console.log('Game successfully updated');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while update:', error);
      }
    } else if (!this.currentId) {
      console.error('currentId is not available');
    }
  }

  takeCard() {
    if (!this.game.pickCardAnimation) {
      this.game.currentCard = this.game.stack.pop()!;
      this.game.pickCardAnimation = true;
      //console.log(this.game.playedCards);

      this.game.currentPlayer++;
      this.game.currentPlayer =
        this.game.currentPlayer % this.game.players.length;

      this.updateGame();

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.game.playedCards.push(this.game.currentCard);
        this.game.pickCardAnimation = false;
        this.updateGame();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  async addPlayer(playerData: string, id: string) {
    this.currentId = id;
    console.log('addPlayer executed, playerData:', playerData);
    console.log('currentID:', this.currentId);
    this.game.players.push(playerData);

    await this.updateGame();
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAddPlayerComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      //name in subscription!?
      /* if (name && name.length > 0) {
        this.game.players.push(name);
        this.updateGame();
      } */
    });
  }
}
```

And the game-model:

```
    export class Player {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
export class Game{
    //public players: Player[] = [];
    public players: string[] = []; 
    public stack: string[] = [];
    public playedCards: string[] = [];
    public currentPlayer: number = 0;
    public pickCardAnimation = false;
    public currentCard: string = '';
    public avatarId: string = '';


    constructor(){
        for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            this.stack.push('hearts_'+i);
            this.stack.push('ace_'+i);
            this.stack.push('clubs_'+i);
            this.stack.push('diamonds_'+i);
        }
        shuffle(this.stack);
    }

    public toJson(){
        return {
            players: this.players,
            stack: this.stack,
            playedCards: this.playedCards,
            currentPlayer: this.currentPlayer,
            pickCardAnimation: this.pickCardAnimation,
            currentCard: this.currentCard,
            avatarId: this.avatarId,
        }
    }
  
}

function shuffle(array:string[]) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  
    // While there remain elements to shuffle.
    while (currentIndex > 0) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element.
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
  
    return array;
  }
```

I hope that you can understand my problem. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you reload an SPA it is expected that all the SPA data is lost. Browsers are designed to start without any data loaded when navigating to a new page.

When you need data to remain in the browser after a reload you need to cache that data or in the browser or in the server providing that webapp's API. This way upon reloading your webapp you can retrieve the data from the cache.

You have a few options to store data, and the most common are (and you can use more than one if necessary):

- Browser's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- Browser's [Cache Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage)
- Server's Session (most webserver applications provide a Session variable/structure for you to store some data)
- Server's Custom storage (where you app does a request for current data upon it's successfully starting)